# How to draw a two-meson exchange feynman diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I wrote this in LaTeX with `tikz-feynman`, but it does not compile:

```latex
\begin{figure}
\centering
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
i1 [particle={\(\Lambda\)}] -- [fermion] a [crossed dot] -- [fermion] i2 [particle={\(n\)}],
i2  -- [fermion] i3 [particle={\(k\)}] ,
i1 -- [draw=none] f1 [particle={\(\Lambda\)}],
i3 -- [draw=none] f3 [particle={\(\Lambda\)}],
a -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] b,
i2 -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] f2,
f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 ,
f2 -- [fermion] f3 [particle={\(n2\)}] ,
};
\caption{Primer DÈBIL}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You should provide an MWE (minimal working  example) that includes everything from  `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some clue as to an expected result the best comment I can give is avoid two particles occupying the same universal continuum thus this diagram is produced by changing the last particle designation from f3 (duplicate of \lambda) to f4 (the designated n2)
[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!